# How to make output ipywidget capture only stdout?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I wish to capture stdout output from a function so that when that function is called for the first time, its output will show in iPython notebook normally, but when it is called for a second time, its output will rewrite the previous output. (So that the previous output will be cleared and the new output shown on the same place)

I have achieved what I want using output ipywidget, though it also captures and clears stderr. Which, unfortunately, is unacceptable as I need to have the stderr output displayed when my program finishes.

Here is a minimal (not) working example of the code I have so far:

```
import sys
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# This function is in some library and cannot be changed
def black_box(iter):
    print('Some output to stdout {}.'.format(iter)) #This is supposed to be cleared on each function call
    sys.stderr.write('Some output to stderr {}.'.format(iter)) #This is NOT supposed to be cleared on each function call

print('Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.')

output = widgets.Output()
display(output)

with output: # I need this to capture only stdout, not stderr ...
    black_box(1)

print('Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.')

with output:
    clear_output() # ... so that this line clears only stdout, not stderr
    black_box(2)
```

The output looks like:

```
Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.
Some output to stdout 2.
Some output to stderr 2.
Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.
```

What I wish the output to look like:

```
Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.
Some output to stdout 2.
Some output to stderr 1.
Some output to stderr 2.
Some other output that is not supposed to be cleared.
```

As you can see, the stderr output was also captured and cleared on the second function call. Does anyone know any way around this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me what widget are you using and how does it interact with the function. I also don't understand why other commands have to be on the same cell, knowing that the widget will be spitting output.

Anyway, here is what I just learned to try to answer your question.

Given this code (works in Colab)

```
import sys
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

w= widgets.ToggleButtons(options=['1','2','3'])
output = widgets.Output()
display(w,output)
#--------------------
# This function is in some library and cannot be changed
def black_box(iter):
  with output:
    output.clear_output()
    print('Inside STD Some output to stdout {}.'.format(iter)) #This is supposed to be cleared on each function call
    sys.stderr.write('INSIDE ERR Some output to stderr {}.'.format(iter)) #This is NOT supposed to be cleared on each function call

  print('Outside STD Some output to stdout {}.'.format(iter)) #This is supposed to be cleared on each function call
  sys.stderr.write('OUTSIDE ERR Some output to stderr {}.'.format(iter)) #This is NOT supposed to be cleared on each function call
#--------------------

# Add a tracker for changes on widget
w.observe(black_box, names = 'value')


print('As usual...')
```

After running the cell I get

[image]

After pressing one button I get

[image]

After pressing another button I get

[image]

(Some) Conclusions:

- OUTSIDE ERR output always stays, i.e. not affected by the clear_output() or the `with`
- STD is always affected by the `clear_output()`, regardless of inside/outside `with`.
- ERR within `with` IS affected by `the clear_output()`

Knowing that I think you have tools to resolve your issue. As many say, if you use a 'fully functional' code in your question, it is easier to give you a 'fully functional answer'.

Note: I just learned about the `with` with `output` thanks to this great article https://medium.com/@socjon/ipywidgets-handler-quick-overview-c9b9246345d9  Many other articles out there just clone the documentation to some degree, this one clearly does not do that.

Note as well that you can place the output wherever you want and even frame it.

```
output = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid yellow'})
output2 = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid pink'})
display(w,output)
....

print('As usual...')
display(output2)
```

Produces
[image]

More info on https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ipython [magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture)? It has options like `--no-stderr` and `--no-stdout`

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately, your solution would affect the output of the entire cell. What I needed was to capture only the output of the function, so that would not work. The ipywidgets output would be perfect for that, unfortunately, according to one of the devs it is not possible to clear only stdout or stderr with the current implementation.